# Multiple aggregations on date ranges in Django

Tags: python, sql, django, sqlalchemy, django-orm

............Models............

```
class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    description = tinymce_models.HTMLField()

class Purchase(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    sale_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
```

I am looking to get an output that says the sum of the purchase prices for a product in the past month and the past week, but want to do this for multiple products.

---

The output would look something like this that i could loop through in my templates...

product1 name-- product1 description  -- sum of product1 weekly sales -- sum of product1 monthly sales

product2 name-- product2 description  -- sum of product2 weekly sales -- sum of product2 monthly sales

---

Should I used raw sql? What would that query look like? Should i try to use sqlalchemy or can i do this in the Django ORM?

Comment: You can make a new dictionary in your views and fill in the sum the sale_date of the last 7 days if thats what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do it in sql statement, because sql performs better to manipulate data, sum and order it... Your code will manage to retrieve data from RDBMS and display it...

I don't know what is your RDBMS, but I give you an exemple in sql server, the syntaxe is around 95% the same in other RDBMS.
You query should looks like something like this :

```
SELECT
    prod.product_id
    ,prod.description
    ,ISNULL(weekSales.priceSum,0) as weekSales
    ,ISNULL(monthSales.priceSum,0) as monthSales
FROM
    Product prod
    left join (
        SELECT
            product_id
            ,sum(price) as priceSum
        FROM Purchase
        WHERE DATEPART(wk,sale_date) = DATEPART(wk,GETDATE())
        GROUP BY product_id) weekSales
        on prod.product_id = weekSales.product_id
    left join (
        SELECT
            product_id
            ,sum(price) as priceSum
        FROM Purchase
        WHERE 
            month(sale_date) = MONTH(GETDATE())
            AND year(sale_date) = year(GETDATE())
        GROUP BY product_id) monthSales
        on prod.product_id = monthSales.product_id
```

[Here you can see a demo of this query with SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d8d57/7)

In sql server,

- GETDATE() return the current date
- DATEPART(wk,[date]) return the week part of a date (WEEK([date]) function in mysql)
- MONTH([date]) return the month part of a date
- YEAR([date]) return the year part of a date
- ISNULL([field],[value_if_null]) replace null value (IFNULL([field],[value_if_null]) in mysql)

You should be able to find similar functions in all RDBMS.

If you need some help in sql, comment above and specify your RDBMS ;)

Hope it helps.